# $x^3+y^3=8$ ,Number of straight lines through origin which do not meet this curve is

Tags: calculus

$x^3+y^3=8$ ,Number of straight lines through origin which do not meet this curve is

Sorry to say that I have no approach for this question, my Brain is totally blank right now. Plz help me.

Comment: Make the ansatz $y=mx$

Comment: only in the first quadrant.  Otherwise it seems like y=-x is an asymptote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a line, say, $y=mx$ does not meet the curve, then $x^3 + (mx)^3 = 8$ has no solutions in $x$.

For $m\neq -1$, we can divide by $1+m^3$ to get a solution. For $m=-1$, there is no solution.

The case of a vertical line through the origin, $x=0$ can easily be verified to intersect the curve.

Comment: It only remains to verify that a _vertical_ line through the origin is not a solution either.

Comment: Edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 3):

All such lines with slope other than -1 meet the curve:

[image]

Comment: Use the `CubeRoot` command in Mathematica (plotting `CubeRoot[8 - x^3]`) to include the part of the curve with $x>2$ as well.

Comment: @MishaLavrov:  Sure... but that won't change the answer.

Comment: Well, right now it looks like a line with slope $-\frac12$ doesn't intersect the curve, even though it does, at $x \approx 2.091$.

Comment: All lines with slope less than $-1$ meet the part of the curve you have plotted.  Only lines with slope $\geq 0$ meet the part of the curve you have plotted.

Comment: @MishaLavrov : `ContourPlot[x^3 + y^3 == 8, ... ]` also works.